# Need to create many python objects by iterating over an excel file

Tags: python, excel, oop, openpyxl

So I've created a class...

```
class Dept_member:
    quarterly_budget = 0
    outside_services = 0
    regular_count = 0
    contractor_count = 0
    gds_function = ''
    dept_name = ''

    def __init__(self, quarterly_budget, outside_services, dept_name):
        self.quarterly_budget = quarterly_budget
        self.outside_services = outside_services
        self.dept_name = dept_name


    def regular_cost(self):
        print "%s" % str((self.quarterly_budget - self.outside_services) / self.regular_count)

    def contractor_cost(self):
        print "%s" % str(self.outside_services / self.contractor_count)
```

Now I want to use variables I collect while iterating over an excel file to create objects for each row using the class detailed above.

```
for row in range(6,d_sh.get_highest_row()):
    if f_sh.cell(row=row, column=2).value:
        deptno = f_sh.cell(row=row, column=2).value
        q_budget = f_sh.cell(row=row, column=17).value #Q3 Actual
        os_budget = f_sh.cell(row=row, column=14).value
        deptnode = f_sh.cell(row=row, column=1).value
        chop = deptnode.split(" ")
        deptname = " ".join(chop[1:])
        Dept = "gds_"+str(deptno)   ### This is what I want my new object to be called! 
        Dept = Dept_member(q_budget, os_budget, deptname)
```

Below are some output from an idle interactive session after this runs.

```
>>> 
>>> deptno
u'180024446'
>>> q_budget
59412.00978792818
>>> os_budget
9973.898858075034
>>> deptnode
u'M180024446 GDS Common HW FEP China'
>>> deptname
u'GDS Common HW FEP China'
>>> Dept
<__main__.Dept_member instance at 0x126c32050>
>>> Dept.quarterly_budget
59412.00978792818
```

What I really wanted was an object named gds_180024446  but instead it mutated the variable.

Is it possible to create a bunch of objects using variables in a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably use python dictionaries ([tutorial page describing dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)), instead of creating bunch of variables using `eval` function:

```
Dept["gds_"+str(deptno)] = Dept_member(q_budget, os_budget, deptname)
```

After that, you can fetch your object from dictionary with:

```
Dept['gds_180024446']
```

Comment: that worked perfectly... Thank you!!! I just fell in love with python and it's community all over again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the eval function like

```
eval("gds_" + str(deptno) + " = Dept_member(q_budget, os_budget, deptname)")
```